# Error when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having this error on importing tensorflow v0.12 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
cortana@cortana:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/node_def_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"m\n\x0eResourceHandle\x12\x0e\n\x06\x64\x65vice\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\tcontainer\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\thash_code\x18\x04 \x01(\x04\x12\x17\n\x0fmaybe_type_name\x18\x05 \x01(\tB4\n\x18org.tensorflow.frameworkB\x13ResourceHandleProtoP\x01\xf8\x01\x01\x62\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

Reading other similar questions, I removed protobuf and tensorflow and installed again. I am still having these errors. What should I try now?

Protobuf: '3.1.0'

Tensorflow: r0.12

CUDA: 8.0.44

Comment: Our government banned github(wtf) !

Comment: WHAT!!!! Where do u live? And whats the reason they gave?

Comment: Of course TURKEY (AMQ)

Comment: Check this module version is valid `Numpy>=1.11.0, six>=1.10.0, protobuf(absolute version)==3.1.0` Otherwise you got an OS level bug(of course you already installed `python-dev` ?)

Comment: All of them are correct versions. I had been using tensorflow last night. Today its giving error. Yes, python-dev is installed. What should I do in case of an OS level bug?

Comment: Some libraries has been changed ! Maybe you make an update after using it ! Check which update processed  last day.

Comment: which update do you mean? pip or ubuntu? Also, how do I check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130226/discussion-between-dsgdfg-and-john-m).

Comment: My previous workaround before v0.10 for this issue is to use "ipython" instead of "python". It's just worth a try. I was on Debian.

Comment: Even that's not working for me :( How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of protobuf version conflict: for me i had python-protobuf v2.6.1 installed from apt-get package manager and while installing tensorflow it installed protobuf v3.3.0 from pip manager

To check version of protobuf from aptitude

```
aptitude versions python-protobuf
```

To check version of protobuf from pip

```
pip show protobuf
```

so i uninstalled both:

```
sudo pip uninstall protobuf
sudo apt-get remove python-protobuf
```

Reinstalled using pip and it solved the issue!!!

```
sudo pip install protobuf
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall  `protobuf` by typing `sudo pip uninstall protobuf` then reinstall by typing `sudo pip install protobuf`
Issue from github https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5168